# How to check focused TextBox in vb.net winforms?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have multiple textbox in a form. How do I know what textbox the cursor  currently is?
Trying to do something like this:

```
If TextBox2.Focus() = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("its in two")
        ElseIf TextBox3.Focus = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("its in three")
        End If
```

But I think its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, it will not work if you are calling your code in a `Button_Click` because when you click the Button then the focus is itself goes to the Button which you have clicked.

**You can do two things:**

Make a combined Focus event for all TextBoxes and check its Sender object.

```
Private Sub TextBox_Focus(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.Enter, TextBox3.Enter
    Dim currTextBox As TextBox = sender

    If currTextBox.Equals(TextBox2) Then
        MessageBox.Show("it's in two")
    ElseIf currTextBox.Equals(TextBox3) Then
        MessageBox.Show("it's in three")
    End If

End Sub
```

**OR**

Take a global string variable, and set its value at each TextBox_Focus event, then check string value in the button click event.

```
 Dim str As String  
 Private Sub TextBox2_Focus(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles TextBox2.Enter
     str = "two"
 End Sub

 Private Sub TextBox3_Focus(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles TextBox3.Enter
     str = "three"
 End Sub

 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles Button1.Click
      MessageBox.Show("it's in " & str)
 End Sub
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind I just edited this a bit to make it compile. You had used TextBox3.Focus instead of TextBox3.Enter as well as comparing with = instead of .equals(). Also, the first example results in a loop because the MessageBox takes focus away from the TextBox but when the user clicks "OK" the TextBox takes focus again and the MessageBox gets called again and so on...

Answer (score 4):

TextBox.Focus actually assigns the focus to the given textbox. What you're looking for is TextBox.Focused. :)

In fact, all form controls have the Focused property.

Comment: The `Focused` property is from the old Windows Forms library, whereas the `IsFocused` is from the new Presentation Core library. I believe there may be some overlap for when and where they may be used.

Answer (score 4):

I know this already has an accepted answer but I just think this method is a bit easier and should be up here for people who find this through Google or whatever.

```
Public focussedTextBox As TextBox
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each control As Control In Me.Controls
        If control.GetType.Equals(GetType(TextBox)) Then
            Dim textBox As TextBox = control
            AddHandler textBox.Enter, Sub() focussedTextBox = textBox
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This way you can then just refer to the focussedTextBox at any time. You should make sure that you check that there is a focussedTextBox before you do however becuase when the application first loads there will not be. You can do this using:

```
If Not focussedTextBox Is Nothing Then
    ...
End If
```

Alternatively, you could set focussedTextBox to a TextBox of your choice on form load, either by setting its value or by focussing the TextBox.

Comment: thanks!!! thanks!!! thanks!!! if you wont put this answer because was an accepted question I wont never found this method to check the type of the control