# how to set a code so that mouse is clicked in the textbox to enter info?

Tags: vb.net

In Visual Basic 2010. I have two textbox and a number keyboard. Every time I click a number, the number is shown in both the textbox. How so I make it so I need to click into the textbox first then the number is only entered in that textbox?? This is what I have in my code. How do I change it so that the textbox has to be clicked for the number to be entered? Thanks!!!

```
 Private Sub btn5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn5.Click
    mtbNum.Text += "5"
    txtQuantity1.Text += "5"
End Sub

Private Sub btn6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn6.Click
    mtbNum.Text += "6"
    txtQuantity1.Text += "6"
End Sub

Private Sub btn7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn7.Click
    mtbNum.Text += "7"
    txtQuantity1.Text += "7"
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the code you already have.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: put a checkbox next to each "use this box" so it is clear to the user whats expected of them to make it work right

Comment: That's quite weird behaviour, can you provide your code sample plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code please.

```
Private Sub btn5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn5.Click
    if mtbNum.Focused = True Then
        mtbNum.Text += "5"
        Exit Sub()
    ElseIf txtQuantity1.Focused = True Then
        txtQuantity1.Text += "5"
        Exit Sub()
    Else
        Exit Sub()
    End If
End Sub
```

This is my last try unless you post more code.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it works kinda when I entered the numbers into mtbNum textbox but when I enter into txtQuantity1, the number is entered into both of the textbox again..

Comment: This has to be done for every key, also, look into KeyPreview method. Then you can capture key presses within the focused textbox only.

Comment: I added to every key. Sorry there was a mistake in my last comment. When I enter a number for txtQuantity1, it shows in mtbNum textbox instead. Also, what is KeyPreview method?

Comment: Is this an onscreen keyboard? Like with Calculator

Comment: Yes, It's an onscreen keyboard. It only has ten buttons with the numbers 1-0.

Comment: try the modification above to separate what we are working with here...

Comment: I tried it already and it almost worked. The only thing is the numbers are entered into only mtbNum textbox no matter which textbox I clicked on.

Comment: Then you will need to paste more code, as something is modifying your textbox. I seriously doubt that something that had millions of man hours put into it will have a but like this that no one has noticed...

Comment: Yeah...it is not working for the modification you made. the numbers are still entered into both textboxes. The one before almost had it but I don't see how that didn't work...

Comment: My code is exactly the same as yours. But the numbers are still shown only in the mtbNum textbox...anyway thank you so much for helping me. I'll figure something out myself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for a VB.Net answer, based on the tag you have selected. Here is a thread talking about similar issue.

[How to check focused TextBox in vb.net winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629171/how-to-check-focused-textbox-in-vb-net-winforms)

Comment: I already checked their answer but it doesn't work for mine. I want to be able to enter numbers from a keyboard I created into different textbox. But everytime I click a number, it enters into all the textbox.

Comment: The snippet of code you entered only shows two textbox, and the code is telling it to enter into both textboxes. See my answer.