# How to set the textbox click event so I can enter numbers to the textbox from an onscreen keyboard?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, event-handling, keyboard, click

In Visual Basic 2010. I have two textbox and an onscreen number keyboard. Every time I click a number, the number is shown in both the textboxes. How do I make it so I need to click into the textbox first then the number is only entered into that textbox?? This is what I have in my code and it is not working. The numbers I tried to enter to the mtbNum textbox and txtQuantity1 is only shown mtbNum textbox no matter which textbox I clicked on. My professor said to change the click event of the textboxes to textbox_click. However I don't know where to go from there. Can someone please help me? How do I change it so that the textbox has to be clicked for the number to be entered? Please and thank you.

```
Private Sub btn5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn5.Click
    If mtbNum.Focus = True Then
        mtbNum.Text += "5"
    ElseIf txtQuantity1.Focus = True Then
        txtQuantity1.Text += "5"
    Else

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub mtbNum_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mtbNum.Click

End Sub

Private Sub txtQuantity1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtQuantity1.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: i don't understand. you want number to be placed in button click event or textbox click event?

Comment: I want to be able to click the number button and that number will appear into one of the textbox. Right now I have two textboxes with one button that I assigned to be the number 5. However, every time I click the button, the number goes into both the textboxes.

Comment: How is this different from earlier? [how to set a code so that mouse is clicked in the textbox to enter info?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462653/how-to-set-a-code-so-that-mouse-is-clicked-in-the-textbox-to-enter-info)

Comment: I didn't solve it earlier and new problems occurred When I tried to fix it...

Answer (score 1):

not clear sure what you want, but I think you are looking for this. I'll delete this if this is not what you are looking for.

solution 1:

```
if txt1.setFocus=true then
'do the button code
else if txt2.setFocus=true then
'do button code
end if
```

solution 2:
*better yet, have a `checkBox` so that the user could clearly choose which `textbox` he/she will enter, say :

```
if chk1.checked = true then
txt1.setFocus
'do button code
else if chk2.checked = true then
txt2.setFocus
'do button code
end if
```