# Determine which textbox on winform has cursor in it

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a Windows Form via VB.net. The form contains two textboxes and an onscreen keyboard that I have programmed myself.

How can I determine which textbox the cursor is currently in, so that the onscreen keyboard will type in the correct textbox?

The application is meant to be entirely touch based.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't check because I'm not at a computer but I believe you're looking for If Textbox1.Focused = true then

Comment: This is already answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629171/how-to-check-focused-textbox-in-vb-net-winforms

Comment: Not in VB.NET but this answer will give you a leading to reach your solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428100/find-out-the-control-with-last-focus

Comment: It is the form's ActiveControl property.  The odds that it is still active when you start poking your finger, well, not so good.  Use osk.exe

Comment: I guarantee you will run into all sorts of unexpected fun with this. It's worth doing, but keep in mind that you will likely have to create a windows hook to intercept mouse events and send keystrokes along to the active application. There is also DotNetBar from DevComponents which is not expensive and contains a great keyboard control.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that your onscreen keyboard is a series a buttons representing a keyboard.

Since you have two text boxes, you have to have a flag for both text boxes to indicate that they have focus, and when one has it the other doesn't.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) _ 
     Handles TextBox1.GotFocus

// These flags are class level variables
textbox1HasFocus = true;
textbox2HasFocus = false;

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_GotFocus(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) _ 
     Handles TextBox2.GotFocus

// These flags are class level variables
textbox2HasFocus = true;
textbox1HasFocus = false;

End Sub
```

For your keyboard events

```
Private Sub KeyBoard_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonA.Click, ButtonB.Click, ButtonC.Click, etc...
    ' I don't know how your using your keyboard, but buttonClickLetter could be determined in multiple ways.  I would use either the Name of the control or even the Tag property for retrieving which letter to use
    String buttonClickLetter = DirectCast(sender, Button).Tag.ToString() 
    If textbox1HasFocus Then
        TextBox1.Text += buttonClickLetter
    ElseIf textbox2HadFocus
        TextBox2.Text += buttonClickLetter
    End If
End Sub
```